How to submit value when checkbox is unchecked when binding variable is string
I have a form with a checkbox,and a hidden input to submit a value if it is unchecked, like this:
<input type="checkbox" name="useDefaultSettings" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_useDefaultSettings" value="on" />

The binding variable in the controller is of type String, however no value is submitted if the checkbox is unchecked.
I know that if the binding variable is of type Boolean this works fine, but is there a way to bind to a String variable instead?
I tried what someone suggested in this post: checkbox not passing parameter when unchecked in spring mvc, to use "!" instead of "_" in the hidden field input as a prefix for the checkbox name, but it didn't work.
